# Why does this recursive function result in 16?

Tags: python, recursion

I've been trying to understand why this results in 16, the most I can figure out is that it becomes either 10 or 18 but I don't understand how it can be 16?

I've tried adding some debugging by printing out at each point but it jumps the result from 8 to 16.

```
def fun(n):

 if (n==4): 
     return n

 else:
     return 2*fun(n+1)

print("Result", fun(2))
```

Any help would be appreciated such as a step by step progression in each recursion?

For instance, I did this:

```
def fun(n):

print ("Called with n = " + str(n))
 if (n==4): 
     return n

 else:
     result = 2*fun(n+1)
     print ("Immediate outcome: " + str(result))
     return result

print("Result", fun(2))
```

Which results in:

Called with n = 2

Called with n = 3

Called with n = 4

Immediate outcome: 8

Immediate outcome: 16

('Result', 16)

Comment: `fun(4) == 4` -> `fun(3) == 2*4 == 8` -> `fun(2) == 2*fun(3) == 16`.

Comment: The computation only involves multiplication. How do you multiply twos and fours to get either 10 or 18? You need a 5 to make 10, and either a nine or two threes to make 18.

Comment: I don't understand the whole concept of working backwards? Why do you get fun(4) first then back to fun(3) then fun(2) to get the result?

Comment: Have you looked for programming tutorials? Understanding recursion should be a common pattern among them. Stack Overflow is not a tutorial site, I'm afraid.

Comment: Well, it does not really go backwards. It actually goes like this: fun(2) = 2*fun(3) = 2*2*fun(4) = 2 * 2 * 4 = 16

Comment: "it jumps the result from 8 to 16" - also called multiplying by 2, as you told it to do

Comment: "Why do you get fun(4) first then back to fun(3) then fun(2) to get the result?" - because to get `fun(2)` you must wait until you get result for `fun(3)` and to get result for `fun(3)` you must wait until you get `fun(4)`. It likes in a company you apply a budget, then you must wait your boss say yes, but your boss need to wait his boss say yes, and his boss also has to wait for his own boss. Only the boss's boss's boss's feedback is returned (`fun(4)` is returned) then the boss's boss will return his feedback (`f(3)`) and then your boss (`f(2)`)

Answer (score 1):

These are the definitions in summary for 2, 3, and 4:

```
fun(2) —> 2 * fun(3)
fun(3) —> 2 * fun(4)
fun(4) —> 4
```

So,

```
fun(2) = 2 * fun(3) = 2 * 2 * fun(4) = 2 * 2 * 4 = 2 * 8 = 16
```

Answer (score 0):

First, it checks if `n = 4`;

If it is not, so it goes to return `2*fun(n+1) fun(n+1)` is then `fun(3)`, which is not `4`.

It then goes to return `2*fun(n+1)` again.

Finally `n == 4`, so it returns `4`, which is then doubled and returned, and doubled and returned again.